# when click button move to another html and show layer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible that when click the button from a.html then move to b.html and show a layer(b.html) ?

I searched some similar example like active tab specific from another HTML.
Using javascript event like hash.location....

Anyone know how to make it and some examples? Thank you

Comment: By "move to another HTML", do you mean changing the page ? If so, just use `window.location`. `layer(div)` does not mean anything. Does "open another HTML" means a popup or a modal ? You need to be clearer and more precise

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 HTML files. Let's say you have a.html and b.html in the same folder.

If I understand correctly, you want to change the page when clicking on a button.

You now have 2 solutions :

- listening to a click on the button
- using a little trick, by having a button element inside a link tag `<a>`.

## Listening to a click on a button

Let's say you have this button in your a.html file :

```
<button id="pageChanger">Change Page</button>
```

Then you need to add this JS :

```
document.getElementById('pageChanger').addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.location = 'b.html';
})
```

(Don't forget that it has to be added at the end of your document, or else it will not load properly

## Having a button inside a link

You just need to add this HTML code :

```
<a href="b.html"><button>Change page</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, suppose two html pages are as follows:

**page1.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'page2.html#myDiv'">Goto Div in Page 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**page2.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv">
        This is my div
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When you click on the ‌`Button` in the first page, window redirects to the `layer` in the second page.

In this example, anchor part is used. The anchor part is the part of the URL after the hash sign (#).

**Example:**

```html
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab#profile-summary'">Go!</button>
```